# Flex: Hand cursor working in Firefox but not in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, apache-flex, cursor, flex3

I am want a hand-cursor wenn the mouse hovers over an Image. I used useHandCursor="true" buttonMode="true" (worked in Firefox but not in IE) and after some research I added mouseChildren="false" (still working in Firefox but not in IE).

I tried to set it over css with styleName and cursor: pointer but this didn't work in either browser.

Someone a suggestion to get the hand for all browsers (FF, IE, Chrome & Safari)?

Comment: Maybe it will help http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7f25.html

Comment: I'm using Flex 3.6 so the link should be: [http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/CursorManager.html](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/managers/CursorManager.html). But isn't there a easier way to achieve this? Without using Listeners to check the cursor position and thus changing the cursor? I'm still surprised that the browsers have different behaviours, it is all flash after all.